# Action defined on tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

If I state that $\text{GL}(V)$ acts on $V\otimes V$ as $$F.x\otimes y := F(x)\otimes F(y),$$ do I have to show something but the 'action-axioms', e.g. well-defined since the $x\otimes y$ are not a basis of $V\otimes V$.

Comment: Not only are they not a basis, they don't exhaust the set. What does a general element of $V\otimes V$ look like? Define the action on that thing. Then, yes, you'd need to show it's well defined.

Comment: But $F$ is $k$-linear and the tensor product is $k$-bilinear and an arbitrary element of $V\otimes V$ is just a $k$-linearcombination of elements of the form $v\otimes w$ with $v,w\in V$. So it should be enough to show that it is well defined on elements such as $v\otimes w$, shouldn't it? Anyway, how can I show that this is well defined via the universal property? This is all I have...

Comment: That was the instructor in me talking :) I guess a better answer is "depends on who is reading it." If it's for a research article, you probably wouldn't need to say more; but if I were grading your homework, I'd want to know what your proposed map did to a linear combination of simple tensors and an argument that the mapping is independent of the representation. The latter is not difficult since you're dealing with vector spaces over a field, but I would still want to see something.